# One-liner to execute a process in a current directory with no output and disown it?

Tags: bash, disown

I'm trying to do something fairly simple:

```
$ ( cd /opt/myprogram && ./myprocess.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 & ; disown $! )
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

How can I bust out a one-liner to, in a sub-shell, execute a given script from a  given folder, nulling the output, and sending it to the background?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you are using both `&` and `;` together. They are both command terminators, and can not be used at the same time. Here is your example fixed:

```
( cd /opt/myprogram && ./myprocess.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown )
```

Comment: I am trying a command on similar lines : bosh -e bosh -d service-fabrik ssh broker -c "tail -F /var/vcap/sys/log/service-fabrik-broker/service-fabrik-broker.log > /var/vcap/sys/log/service-fabrik-broker/error.log 2>&1 & disown" , but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea what could be wrong ? 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) utility was designed for pretty much what you're looking for:

```
Usage: nohup COMMAND [ARG]...
  or:  nohup OPTION
Run COMMAND, ignoring hangup signals.

If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from /dev/null.
If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if possible,
'$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise.
If standard error is a terminal, redirect it to standard output.
To save output to FILE, use 'nohup COMMAND > FILE'.
```